# How to share File Watchers between projects in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, file-watcher

Is there any way to share File Watcher settings between different projects in IntelliJ?

When I go into the settings for File Watchers it says "For current project", however there is no way to change this to a global setting.